# SmackException$NoResponseException

Tags: android, asmack

I am using asmack 4.0.7 and eclipse.

This is my code that I use to connect to server:

```
config = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.43.214", 5223);
// config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(10000L);
connection.connect();
connection.login(session.getUsername(), session.getRamz());
```

And the logcat:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.throwConnectionExceptionOrNoResponse(XMPPConnection.java:548)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwConnectionExceptionOrNoResponse(XMPPTCPConnection.java:867)
05-14 18:17:04.348: W/System.err(6068):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader.startup(PacketReader.java:113)
05-14 18:17:04.348: W/System.err(6068):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initConnection(XMPPTCPConnection.java:482)
05-14 18:17:04.348: W/System.err(6068):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:440)
05-14 18:17:04.348: W/System.err(6068):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:811)
05-14 18:17:04.348: W/System.err(6068):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:396)
05-14 18:17:04.348: W/System.err(6068):     at service.ChatService$Connect.doInBackground(ChatService.java:193)
05-14 18:17:04.348: W/System.err(6068):     at service.ChatService$Connect.doInBackground(ChatService.java:1)
05-14 18:17:04.348: W/System.err(6068):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-14 18:17:04.348: W/System.err(6068):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-14 18:17:04.353: W/System.err(6068):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-14 18:17:04.353: W/System.err(6068):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-14 18:17:04.353: W/System.err(6068):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-14 18:17:04.353: W/System.err(6068):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but I had this line of code in OnDestroy and after a lot of tracking and debugging, I found it is causing the issue:

```
if (run != null)
    run.cancel(true);
```

*run is the AsyncTask which the application uses to connect to server.

I commented out the 2 lines and app is now connecting to the server with no problems.